# Google Analytics: Are custom metrics "integers only" when sent in through the measurement protocol?

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

We need to send a decimal value to google analytics, and had decided to do this using a custom metric of the type "Currency". In the Tracking documentation it says that this should be allowed:

> If the custom metric is configured to have a currency type, you can send decimal values.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets#sending_data

However, we are sending in raw data using the measurement protocol, and in *that* documentation it says that only integers are allowed for custom metrics:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#cm_

I have noticed that the decimal values we send in do not show up in the UI. Could this be the reason?

Comment: What does the https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/ return?  I wonder if its the website that just cant display decimals.   Measurement protocol should be accepting them

Comment: If you can verify somehow that you are sending a decimal to a custom metric with the measurement protocol and the query explorer is returning a int and not the decimal we can log it as a bug and I will ping Google for you.    Either way I think the documentation is a bit confusing I agree with you there.

Comment: After many failed attempts, I managed to get the data into analytics. It turns out that it was _another_ field that was causing the requests to fail, namely eventvalue, where we also used a decimal. Turns out that eventvalue can only be integers.

Comment: If you didn't know about them try https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/validating-hits and https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/ very useful when sending stuff to Google Analytics.   I have been there last week I spent two days on an invalid request :/

Comment: My findings: 1. Decimals are accepted for custom metrics. The documentation for the measurement protocol should be updated. 2. The status code 200 that is returned does in fact _not_ mean 200 at all if a value was incorrectly formatted. I would consider that a bug.

Comment: The hitbuilder is indeed awesome! I was unaware of it at first, but my colleague pointed me to it, and it was then that I noticed the problem with eventvalue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Custom metrics are not limited to just integer types. They can be whatever type you want, as long as it corresponds to the type you set when [creating them](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709829?hl=en&ref_topic=2709827#set_up_custom_metrics) in the Google Analytics admin interface.

In short: custom metric values should be integers for metrics of type *Integer* or *Time*, and they can be integers or floating point numbers for metrics of type *Currency*.

The documentation was incorrect (when this question was asked), but it has been updated to clarify this ambiguity.